# Cassandra CQL incompatibility between cql2 and cql3

Tags: cassandra, cql

it seems like adding a new column on the fly doesnt work in Cassandra CQL3; say i have this table:

> cqlsh:Keyspace2> select * from users;
>
> user_name | birth_year | gender | password   | session_token | state
>
> -----------+------------+--------+------------+---------------+-------
>
> jsmith |       1968 |   null |  ch@ngem3a |          null |  null
>
> jsmith2 |       1963 |   null | ch@ngem3a2 |          null |  null
>
> cqlsh:Keyspace2> insert into users (user_name, x) values ('jsmith',100);

**>Bad Request: Unknown identifier x**

> Perhaps you meant to use CQL 2? Try using the -2 option when starting cqlsh.

but the warning is correct, the same thing works when i go to CQL2:

```
> Blockquote

cqlsh:Keyspace2> exit
[root@bdvm1 ~]# cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 2.2.0 | Cassandra 1.1.9-dse-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 2.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.33.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use Keyspace1;
cqlsh:Keyspace1> select * from users;
 KEY   | birth_year | gender
-------+------------+--------
  TEST |       1968 |      m
  TEST1 |       1968 |      f

cqlsh:Keyspace1> insert into users (KEY, x) values ('jsmith',100);
cqlsh:Keyspace1> select * from users;
 KEY,TEST | birth_year,1968 | gender,m
 KEY,TEST1 | birth_year,1968 | gender,f
 KEY,jsmith | x,100
```

Does anyone know why ? I would have thought CQL3 was backwards compatible ..

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

You need to read http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts and http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3.  The first in particular explains why CQL2 could not model many common Cassandra design patterns, and how we addressed those in CQL3.

Short answer: What CQL2 called "dynamic columns in a row" are represented as "multiple rows in a partition" in CQL3.  To reduce confusion, we now refer to the raw storage engine atom of name:value as a cell, rather than a column, and a group of cells with a common key as a partition.

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer will be NO, CQL3 is backwards-incompatible (Refer [cql3 experts](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts)). But it does not mean they have broken their commitment of backward compatibility. The base API behind CQL3 is still Thrift API, which has the same functionality since 0.7, its just the matter the implementation style has changed. .